# Bash - Command and variable expansion

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables, variable-expansion

After reading the [POSIX Shell manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) and the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) I still can't explain the following behavior:

```
% bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
% bash
% A=1 B=$A bash -c 'echo $B'
1
% A=1 B=$A bash -c 'echo $B'

%
```

Other shells like zsh or ksh are doing what I would expect, which would be to display '1' all the time. So it seems to be specific to Bash.

Could someone explain this behavior and if possible point to where it's explained in the documentation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for me ,it displays 1 every time

Comment: It prints 1 for me every time (bash 4.2.45)

Comment: Which version of bash are you using?

Comment: Thanks @knittl for putting me on the right track. The issue was the Bash version I was using. After downloading and compiling Bash 4.2.0, it's indeed working as expected.

Comment: Confirmed, bash 3.2 (OSX).

Comment: Presumably, zsh (and ksh, bash 4, etc.) runs the assignments in series, and bash 3.2 does them in parallel.

Comment: `bash` has had some issues with incorrectly caching values related to pre-command environment variables; this looks like one that got fixed. Something similar involving `IFS` and input redirection is still outstanding, although corrected in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour seems to be specific to Bash 3.2 and the snippet works as expected on later versions, as 4.2.